# Which version of JBoss AS to use?

Tags: jboss

We are using JBoss 4.2 GA, and need use a newest version in some new project.
I heard that JBoss 5.0 encounter such bugs... is this correct?
If not, which exact version of 5.0 to use?? and what about 6.0??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JBoss AS 5.1 is perfectly fine. Every app server has bugs, they're big, complex applications in themselves, but 5.1 is solid.

JBoss AS 6 hasn't been released yet, it's still in beta.

Answer (score 1):

Jboss Application Server 7 is released, and up to a beta version of 7.1.0. You can download a copy [here](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/downloads), and find the Getting Started Guides [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Getting+Started+Guide).

As with any major revision of an application server, there are significant changes that might impact upon your business and will need to be considered in the context of your use case. Being an open source project, the early praise and early bugs are in the public arena, so it is easy to research for yourself.

Working on a documentation project involving AS7 I have seen some of the great work that the team has undertaken, and I couldn't imagine going back to a previous version now I've enjoyed the fast boot-up times, the ease of application deployment, custom configuration and the powerful [Management CLI](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/CommandLineInterface).

These kinds of improvements and features, not just constrained to JBoss Application Server or JBoss Enterprize Application Platform, speak volumes about the speed, stability and usability that will be increasing exponentially in this field for all competitors over the coming years. I'd urge you to check out the current generation of application servers if your experience is largely with JBoss AS 4.2.